# Multiple condition if elseif statement

Tags: php, if-statement, conditional-statements

i have a small problem trying to echo the data from database with some conditions.
The issue is that in the same table i have 3 different values at the same hour.

The filter with if statement is working excelent, the only problem is that if there is found "name1 from 07 to 08 and week 1" and "name2 from 07 to 08 and week 2" is showing both.

My question is, how can i show only 1 according the filters?

Please have a lok at the database structure and php script.

```
//**    Table structure

     id name    week    start   end
    1   name1   1   07  08
    2   name2   1   08  09
    3   name3   2   07  08
    4   name4   3   07  08

     //$week    -> 1 from 1 to 5, 2 Saturday, 3 Sunday
     //$start   -> 07, 08 ... 14, hours
     //$end     -> 07, 08 ... 14, hours

     $Date = date('H');
     $user = '';
     $pass = '';
     $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=mydatabase', $user, $pass);
     foreach($dbh->query('SELECT * from table') as $row):
        $week = $row['week'];
        $start = $row['start'];
        $end = $row['end'];

     if(($Date >= $start) && ($Date < $end) && ($week == 1)):
        echo 'This Week i will show this name' . $row['name'];

     elseif(($Date >= $start) && ($Date < $end) && ($week == 2)):
        echo 'This Saturday i will show this name' . $row['name'];

     elseif(($Date >= $start) && ($Date < $end) && ($week == 3)):
        echo 'This Sunday i will show this name' . $row['name'];
     endif;
     endforeach;

    $dbh = null;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You can `break;` after you find one.

Comment: i'm pretty sure this can be handled better in `db query` than in `php`..

Comment: Excelent, if this will pass the first if no found nothing there and second if nothing too, your solution is great !. Thanks

Comment: @vlzvl Can you please explain more about "db query than in php", Thanks.

Comment: you can insert the name in an array whenever you find a new name along with the week.. so if name already exists so insert it in that array.. else ignore it.. so the array will have unique name and the first week when the name comes..

Comment: I understand, is a small database that will show the name if the actual hour is x and week y. no need to be too complicated. I think. Thanks a lot. Dario

Comment: @Dario i meant you can replace the `IF` conditions in `PHP` with `WHERE/AND` in PDO and reduce the results, thus without needing a loop at the end (or im making a grave error here that i cannot see)

Comment: I understand, you mean SELECT * FROM table where week 1 and start = $start or ? and end $end or ?. Thanks